# How to create global components in React Native that can be rendered by a function Call (Like Alert.alert)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I create components in React Native that can be called from anywhere in the App using a Function Call. What I mean is just Like we call Alert.alert("heading 1", 'heading 2')and it displays a Dialog Box, Without having to add  in our Component tree. I am trying to create my own Custom Dialog Box and I want to call it using MyAlert.alert() or something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Honestly i have no idea where to start.

Comment: you could start with [Alert](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/alert) or [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/modal)